# time -f "%e[s]" sleep 3 prints -f: command not found

Tags: bash, ubuntu, time

When I use `time` to measure elapsed time during command(s) execution with no options given, like this:

```
time sleep 3
```

It behave correctly, it prints:

```
real    0m3,002s
user    0m0,002s
sys     0m0,000s
```

But providing any option, like -f or -o (anything other than -p) it prints weird error messgage.

In example:

```
time -f "%e[s]" sleep 3
```

prints

```
-f: command not found
```

(using bash on Ubuntu 18.04.2)

Do I miss something obvious?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is something special with `time` : it exists as a shell built-in AND as a binary :

- `type time` returns : `time is a shell keyword`
- `type /usr/bin/time` returns : `/usr/bin/time is /usr/bin/time`

Then :

```
time -f "%e[s]" sleep 3
bash: -f: command not found

real    0m0.003s
user    0m0.003s
sys     0m0.000s
```

whereas :

```
/usr/bin/time -f "%e[s]" sleep 3
3.00[s]
```

Comment: Ahh, bash has it built in! Thanks for clarification, running with /usr/bin/time works as expected - at least by me :)